# Copy file and append modified date in batch script

Tags: batch-file

So I would like to create a batch script so that I could put it in my SendTo folder. I would like it to do the following:

When I select the script in my send to window, I would like it to make a copy of the file to the same directory but add the date (_YYYYMMDD) to the following. So if the file is called

test.txt

and I send it to the script, it should make a new file called

test_YYYYMMDD.txt

I have a script that adds the current date, but I would like one to do the last modified date. The current script I have is the following:

```
@echo off

:: Tokenize date for format yyyymmdd
For /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%A in ('Date /t') do ( 
Set Month=%%A
Set Day=%%B
Set Year=%%C
Set All=%%C%%A%%B
)

copy %1 "%~d1%~p1%~n1_%All%%~x1"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `copy "%~1" "%~dpn1_%All%%~x1"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

rem Get the file date
for /f %%f in ('forfiles /p "%~dp1\" /m "%~nx1" /c "cmd /c echo @fdate"') do (

    rem Split the date by commonly used separators
    for /f "delims=.,/ tokens=1,2,3" %%a in ("%%f") do (

        rem Zero-pad month and day
        set month=0%%a
        set day=0%%b

        rem Rename the file to FileName_YYYYMMDD.Ext
        copy /b "%~1" "%~dpn1_%%c!month:~-2!!day:~-2!%~x1"
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: This isn't working as expected, it's not creating a copy of the file at all.

Comment: I thought you would remove the `echo` before `copy` :-) See the updated code and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Gotcha. It makes the copy now, but for my test, the modified date was 5/28/2014, and it made the file


`test_2014528.pdf`


when I would like it like


`test_20150528.pdf`



Is this possible? Thanks again, this is a huge help

Comment: I get what the code is supposed to do now, but now it's not creating the copy again.

Comment: Updated. Previously I've only tested in a console window, not via the menu.

Comment: I don't understand this, where do I put the folder I'm trying to rename files inside? I get error directory name invalid.

Comment: It should be the first parameter when calling the batch file.